# redirect with saving url params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2, redirecttoroute

some time ago forum was created in public directory of a rails app. then forum was moved to a sub-domain.
I've created a redirect for 'domain.com/forum' => 'forum.domain.com by editing routes & creating redirect action.
My question is: how may i preserve url params (ex. 'domain.com/forum?thread1&=1' => 'forum.domain.com?thread1=1' & etc.)
My code as follows:

> routes.rb:
>      map.forum '/forum', :controller => "application",
>   :action => "redirect_to_forum"
>
> application_controller.rb
>    def redirect_to_forum
>       redirect_to "http://forum.domain.com"
>   end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with getting request url in a hash :-> and then try to preserve your parameters,

on the top of the page use

```
require 'cgi'
```

and then get the url wherever you want to get it and use it. After getting parameters in hash u can use them to reconstruct your new url.

```
 parameters  = CGI::parse(request.url)
```

parameter will contain the hash of your all parameters.